# How do I run gremlin queries through OrientDB http api

Tags: orientdb-2.1

#### in the browser studio I **CAN** run the following command:

`select gremlin("g.v('12:0')") from #12:0`
and i get a result.

#### with the http api I **CAN** run the following command:

`<server>:[<port>]/command/pokeloungestage/sql/select * from #12:0`
and i get a result.

#### with the http api I can **CAN NOT** run the following command:

`<server>:[<port>]/command/pokeloungestage/sql/select gremlin("g.v('12:0')") from #12:0`

#### with postman I **CAN** run the following command:

---with proper auth & cookie headers

`<server>:[<port>]/command/pokeloungestage/gremlin/g.v("12:0")`

#### with the http api I **CAN NOT** run the following command:

`<server>:[<port>]/command/pokeloungestage/gremlin/g.v("12:0")`

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was running GET requests, gremlin http API must use POST method.